# Form submission after Javascript Validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I want to submit my form to a `PHP` file called `reg.php` after validating it using `JavaScript`. The `HTML` form is given below:

**HTML Form:**

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username"></input>        
   <button type="button" onclick="val()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript Validation**

The following is the `JavaScript` validation code:

```
function val(){

    var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
    if(!uname){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Enter a username";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        // I want to submit form if this else statement executes.
    }


}
```

Comment: If you change the button to `type="submit"` and put `onclick="return val();"` then the form will submit automatically unless your function returns `false` (as it does when validation fails). Just add `action="reg.php"` to the form element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add `action="reg.php"` in `<form>` and `return val()` functions on `onclick`, also make `type="submit"` to form submission, like:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form method="post" action="reg.php">
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username"></input>        
   <button type="submit" onclick="return val()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

Just add **`return true;`** in `else` like:

```
function val(){

    var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
    if(!uname){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Enter a username";
        return false;    // in failure case
    }        
    return true;    // in success case
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can submit it with form `name` in else section.

```
document.myForm.submit();
```

---

```
 var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
 if (!uname) {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Enter a username";
      return false;
 } else {
      document.myForm.submit(); // Form will be submitted by it's name
 }
```

**Markup**

```
<form method="post" name="myForm">.....</form>
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/09vrnzmh/)

Comment: remember to add the action at <form action="your_file.php">

Answer (score 2):

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return val()">
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username">       
     <button type="submit" >Sign Up</button>
 </form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function val(){

     var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
     if(!uname){
         document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Enter a username";
         return false;
     }
     else{
         return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: well, i have a question..in form you are using onsubmit and then you are using button type with onclick? can you please share little bit info with answer then it will be great..sorry for my question.

Comment: let me explain it , i did the answer like this now , some one sent to me something like if you approved some change , i considered like modifying just shape not the script , but he change it , so i edited to my original answer .

Comment: but my question is you are calling function onsubmit when you are not using submit button..sorry m not good in php so asking..please don't mind..thanx

Comment: you are right , it should be type="submit" , I'll change it , thanks

Comment: sometimes , id don't go deep in code at such issue because i consider that the one who asked is covered , so i copied it as it is , but i was wrong , thanks

Comment: Well on SO you are lucky that you did not get downvotes..so change or removed before you got..:P

Answer (score 0):

Here is, you need to get the form element and `submit()` it, so you need to add the id to the form and the `action` attribute to the `reg.php` file:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/jmss4372/)

```
<form method="post" id="theForm" action="reg.php">
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username"></input>        
   <button type="button" onclick="val()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function val() {
    var uname = document.getElementById('username').value;
    if (!uname) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Enter a username";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a return true statement in the else block and then change the form to this.

```
<form method="post" action="reg.php">
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username"></input>        
   <button type="submit" onclick="return val()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```